# Changing DICOM tags using dcm4che

Tags: java

I am stuck on a piece of code that I have written that uses [dcm4che](http://www.dcm4che.org). I have made a whole heap of nested ifs and I want to find a way to convert to a switch-case (problem being I have no way of declaring an int that can distinguish between cases). Is there an alternative to making this code snippet appear less ugly?

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.dcm4che2.data.DicomObject;
import org.dcm4che2.data.Tag;
import org.dcm4che2.data.VR;
import org.dcm4che2.io.DicomInputStream;
import org.dcm4che2.io.DicomOutputStream;
import org.dcm4che2.io.StopTagInputHandler;
import org.dcm4che2.util.CloseUtils;



/**
 * Steps to doing this. 
 * 1.) Read from DCM file and convert to DCM Object
 * 2.) Read from text file 
 * 3.) Add tags to ArrayList
 * 4.) Compare ArrayList of tags to DCM Object
 * 5.) Match tags and associate tags with VR code which will automatically add Strings/values into tag.
 * 6.) Save new copy into a directory prompted by user.
 * @author Ryan
 *
 */
public class changeTags {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static DicomObject dcmObj;
    public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void promptForTagLocation() throws IOException
    {
        //Turns DCM file into object
        System.out.println("Please Enter DICOM File Location: ");
        String dicomLocation = input.next();
        changeToDICOMObject(dicomLocation);

        //Reading text tag location
        System.out.println("From what TXT File are you reading the tags that need changing: ");
        String tagChangeText = input.next();
        readFromTextFile(tagChangeText);
    }
    public void changeToDICOMObject(String path)
    {
        DicomInputStream din = null;
        try {
            din = new DicomInputStream(new File(path));
            dcmObj = din.readDicomObject();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        finally {
            try {
                din.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ignore) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Now reading DCM File");
    }
    public void readFromTextFile(String path) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(new File(path));
        while (read.hasNext())
        {
            list.add(read.next());
        }
        System.out.println("Reading from tag List....");
        System.out.println("Changing dicom tags...");
        read.close();
        matchTags();
    }
    public void matchTags() throws IOException
    {
        try 
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                String replaceTag = list.get(i).toString().replaceAll("[(),]", "");
                int valueofReplaceTag = (int)Long.parseUnsignedLong(replaceTag, 16);
                if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.DA))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "20150101");
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.DT))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "20150101");
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.SH))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "testingThis");
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.AE))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "test");
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.CS))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "testingThis");
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.LO))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "testingThis");
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.PN))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "testingThis");
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.ST))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "testingThis");
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.LT))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "testingThis");
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.UT))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "testingThis");
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.AS))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "25");
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.DS))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "25");
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.UL))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putInt(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), 25);
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.SL))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putInt(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), 25);
                    }
                    else if(dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag).equals(VR.TM))
                    {
                        dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag), "22:00");
                    }
            }
                System.out.println("Where is the new DCM file being saved to? Please enter directory (Include File name and Extension): ");
                String directoryPath = input.next();
                File out = new File(directoryPath);
                DicomOutputStream dos = new DicomOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(out)));
                dos.writeDicomFile(dcmObj);

                CloseUtils.safeClose(dos);

        System.out.println("Tags have been successfully changed!");
        menu.showMenu();
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a mapping of your replacements, as follows:

```
private static final Map<VR, String> stringReplacements = new HashedMap<>();
static {
  stringReplacements.put(VR.DA, "20150101");
  stringReplacements.put(VR.DT, "20150101");
  stringReplacements.put(VR.SH, "testingThis");
  // ....
}

private static final Map<VR, Integer> intReplacements = new HashedMap<>();
static {
  intReplacements.put(VR.UL, 25);
  // ....
}
```

Note that I've created two different maps, as you substitute both strings and ints. You could have one map of `Object` values, but then your replacement code needs to do `instanceof` checks.

Your long series of conditional statements then reduces to:

```
VR replaceTagVR = dcmObj.vrOf(valueofReplaceTag);

String s = stringReplacements.get(replaceTagVR);
if (s != null) {
  dcmObj.putString(valueofReplaceTag, replaceTagVR, s);
}

Integer i = intReplacements.get(replaceTagVR);
if (i != null) {
  dcmObj.putInt(valueofReplaceTag, replaceTagVR, i);
}
```

Comment: I like it, when i get the chance, i will implement it that way. Thanks :)

Comment: worked out really good.